# PHP array question

Tags: php

I have a array called $A which contains only non zero positive numbers.

Now I need to find any number of distinct consecutive subarrays that have a given sum.

I will explain with example

```
$A = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

and the sum I am looking for is `5`.

Then there are `(2, 3)` and `(5)`.

I tried searching and got a python code. I've translated it to PHP below but it refuses to work

```
$s = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($A); $i++){
     for($j=$i; $j < count($A); $j++){
         $s = $s + $A[$j];
         if($s == $sum) {
             echo "[" . $i . " " . $j . "]";
         }
     }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What is `$B`? And when will `$j < count($B)` be true?

Comment: Also, why don't you post the Python code?

Comment: You are searching only "binomial sums" ? And you forgot (1 4) ;)

Comment: @thephpdeveloper "distinct consecutive subarrays" - but I guess that it depends on interpretation :)

Comment: I don't understand what is $B ?

Comment: So $B is an array that you want to sum up to match your given number or what? Not sure I understood exactly where you're going here.

Comment: He's searching consecutive sums. So no (1 4).

Comment: This might be the wrong place for this but, shouldn't he figure this out on his own?  If this is indeed homework he will see this, in some form or another, on a test, that he is going to fail because he doesn't understand the concepts at work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :

```
$A = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$size = count($A);
$sum = 5;
$solution = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $tempsum = 0;
    for($j=$i; $j < $size && $tempsum < $sum; $j++) {
        $tempsum += $A[$j];
        if($tempsum === $sum) {
            $solution[] = array_slice($A, $i, $j - $i + 1);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($solution);
```

As for your code, there's several mistake in it :

1. You must reinitialize $s each time in the loop.
2. The array $B probably doesn't exist (second loop stop condition).
3. It won't show a proper result when the length of the subarray is greater than 2.
4. There's no need the second loop go to the end, as soon as the temporary sum is greater than the searched one, we can stop.

Answer (score 2):

- `count($A)`, you have no `$B`
- `$s = 0;` inside the first loop
- don't forget that `$i` and `$j` are indexes and they start at `0`
- don't forget to give a value to `$sum` before you start searching
- `if($s > $sum)` you may want to `continue;` from the second loop

Good luck,
Alin

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `$s` to `0` at the start of the inner loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($A); $i++){
    $s = 0;  // CHANGE HERE.
     for($j=$i; $j < count($A); $j++){
         $s = $s + $A[$j];
         if($s == $sum) {
             echo "[" . $i . " " . $j . "]";
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11); // the array to search in
$b = array(); // the resulting array
$sum = 9; // the sum to search for

$w = $a; // $w is the working array which we may modify
$n = count($w); // number of elements in source array
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
    $x = 0;
    $t = array();
    if($w[$i] == $sum){
        $b[] = array($w[$i]);
    }
    if($w[$i] >= $sum){
        break;
    }
    for($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++){
        $x += $w[$j];
        $t[] = $w[$j];
        if($x == $sum){
            $b[] = $t;
        }
        if($x >= $sum){
            break; // already found the array, continue search
        }
    }
}
```

`$b` will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

Comment: When you're searching for a subarray, you can stop as soon as $x > $sum. And sorting is in my opinion wrong since we're looking for consecutive subarrays of the array, sorting will potentially change the sequence.

Comment: Well, I did stop the search when `($x == $sum)`.

Comment: yeah, but this isn't enough, `$x` can "jump over" `$sum` and then you will do the entire loop for nothing, since $x is already greater than $sum.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
<?php
    $a = array(1,2,3,4,5);

    $l = sizeof($a);

    for($i=0; $i<$l; $i++)
    {
        for($j=$i+1; $j<$l; $j++)
        {
            if($a[$i]+$a[$j] == 5)
                echo "( ".$a[$i]." , ".$a[$j]." ) <br/>";
        }
        if($a[$i]==5)
            echo "( ".$a[$i]." )<br/>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This will give wrong results in many cases. It won't return subarrays longer than 2 element. It will return [1, 4] which is not consecutive. And you can easily avoid the last part of the loop which is totally redundant.